# 80's (?) book about the life of an unusual captain of a starship, who is both male and female

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a (paperback) book in the late 80's about the struggles of a starship captain who struggled against prejudice and other issues, because he was born of the union of two different beings. This captain, as a result, was biologically both male and female.

The book, as I recall, was named after his/her starship - and I remember that the author's name began with initials (like C.J.? or the like). I also remember that the author's name may have been a pen name and that the author was a woman.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._J._Cherryh

Comment: No clue about the book at the moment, but one possible author might be C J Cherryh - female and the right initials.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: One of the Vorkosigian books? http://archive.li/geYKY

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far. It is not the Vorkosigian Saga universe, but thanks for that link. CJ Cherryh seems like a good bet for the author, so I am going to comb through her books. <fingers crossed>

Comment: @Valorum: Bel was never a starship captain, AFAIK. (And being Betan, it had no issues about being a hermaphrodite.)

Comment: The description doesn't match any C.J. Cherryh book I've read, and while I'm a couple of years behind in the _Foreigner_ universe books, I've read everything else.

Comment: Were there other people on the ship? Military, civilian?

Comment: Yes - The starship and its unusual captain became quite famous - had a crew. Engaged in interstellar wars? The book chronicles the captain's conception, the prejudices he/she faced, through his/her adventures - right up to the end of his life, surrounded by family and grandchildren. He/She wasn't just a simple hermaphrodite - his/her species actually "morphed" between male and female (meaning "he" could have children - He/she was a hybrid species (parents were star-crossed - forgive the term - lovers, as told in a prologue)